# How can I revert the order of digits of an integer

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I revert the order of digits of an integer?

If `x1 = 59097585` then I want to receive `x2 = 58579095`.

Comment: Take a look at `IntegerDigits`, `FromDigits` and `Reverse`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a builtin `IntegerReverse` function:

```
IntegerReverse[59097585]
```

> `58579095`

Answer (score 4):

```
FromDigits @ StringReverse @ ToString @ x1 (* or *)
FromDigits @ StringReverse @ IntegerString @ x1
```

> 58579095

or

```
With[{id = IntegerDigits[x1]}, 10^Range[0, Length[id] - 1].id]
```

> 58579095